# Realization of Voevodsky Motives over a perfect field in mixed categories.

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, motives

Let $k$ be a finite field and $l$ be different from characteristic of $k$. Is there a realization functor from the Voevodsky's category with $\mathbb Q$ coefficients to the constructible mixed étale category of sheaves over $k$ such that $M_{gm}(X)\mapsto \mathcal Rp_*p^*1_k$ for *any* scheme $X$ (of finite type, seperated over $k$)?

(This is true for $X$ smooth by work of Florian Ivorra -- "Realisation l-Adique
des Motifs Triangules Geometriques, I." and using deJong's resolutions and Galois descent, I suspect this should be true for all $X$. However, there is a issue related to "functoriality" of the cone which seems to be an obstacle for deducing this directly in the triangulated categories and I am stuck).

Comment: Can you work with the underlying model categories (where the cone IS functorial)?

Comment: @name I don't know. I am not very comfortable with the whole jargon of model categories et al and hence was expecting a concrete answer in this context.

[ The actual object I am interested in is this: $Hom_{DM_{gm}(k)}(M_{gm}(X)[r],1_k)$. For $X$ smooth, this is related to motivic cohomology/higher chow groups and is non-zero only for $r=0$ where it is $\mathbb Q$ if one is working with rational coefficients. For $X$ singular, I want to compare this with étale cohomology via realizations and conclude a similar result for some schemes which perhaps are not smooth. ]

Comment: You don't need the Jargon of model categories, as everything ends up being contained in DM_{gm} which is obtained in a straight-forward way from the category of chain complexes in the additive category SmCor(k).

Comment: If you are willing to assume resolution of singularities, what you want would result from the analogue in the derived category of l-adic sheaves of the blow-up distinguished triangle mentioned in Section 2.2 of "Triangulated categories of motives over a field" (If you check Proposition 4.1.3 $X_Z \to X$ is any proper birational morphism, not necassarily a blowup).

Comment: and I guess this follows from proper base change and the conservativity of $(i^*, j^*)$ where $(i, j)$ is a closed-open immersion complementary pair.

Comment: The argument I'm thinking of is in Proposition 3.7 of http://arxiv.org/abs/1003.1487

Comment: @name yes, that was what I was trying, but then realized that in the "induction step" (using the blow up triangle) I will need to know the morphisms correctly, which will difficult given non-uniqueness of the cone (the center of blow up has been calculated using "induction", hence via cones).

But you are right, there is a natural category of complexes $SmCor(k)$ which I was not looking at.



Comment: Will look at the arxiv paper and revert.

Comment: Oh I see your functoriality problem now. If you just want an isomorphism $\phi(M_{gm}(X)) \cong Rp_*p^*1_k$ for each (non-smooth) scheme I think you can get this working with chain complexes by iterating the cones like you said. However you won't know that it is a natural transformation between $\phi(M_{gm}(-))$ and $R-_*-^*1_k$. So this is not very satisfying.

Comment: In Lemma 4.5 of Ivorra's first article can you see why the first statement involves all schemes but the second one only the smooth ones? He seems to have potentially defined the realisation for all schemes so I would hope that there is a good reason why his final theorem only includes smooth ones.

Comment: No you won't even get a isomorphism $\phi(M_{gm}(X))\cong Rp_*p^*1_k$. As I said in "induction step" functoriality will be needed.


Comment: Regarding Lemma 4.5 of Ivorra, I may be able to comment when I am done reading till that point (but that may take quite some time -- I am very tied up with several things right now.). 

Comment: Incidentally, what application do you have in mind?

Comment: See Proposition 2.1.1, assertion 14 (and 2) of my preprint http://arxiv.org/abs/1105.0420 (page 19), its proof, and the papers cited.

Comment: In order to apply the statement I cited you will also need a description of $M_{gm}(X)$ given by Cisinski and Deglise and Verdier duality.

Comment: I do recall seeing this paper, but the proof of assertion 14 is postponsed to a future one. Will be looking forward to it!

Answer (score 1):

In principle, the answer is yes.

The question is what do you mean by $M_{gm}(X)$ if $X$ is not smooth. For smooth $X$, $M_{gm}(X)$ can be defined as $f_\sharp f^* 1$. Here $f: X \to k$ is the structural map and $1$ is the unit (=motive of $k$). This expression is isomorphic to $f_! f^! 1$ by relative purity, provided that $f$ is smooth. If you define the motive with the latter formula in general, then the question becomes whether the realization functor converts $f_!$ to $(R)f_* $ and $f^!$ to $f^* $. Such statements are proven by Ayoub in his paper on etale realizations. (I don't remember exactly, it is possible that Ayoub requires the map to be quasi-projective. Also note that his paper mostly studies a covariant realization functor, in which case $f^*$ commutes with the realization functor. The change to $f^!$ comes when you switch to the more classical language of contravariant realization functors.)